# « けんもほろろ » : soulignant une attitude froide avec laquelle quelqu'un refuse catégoriquement une demande

Tags: expressions, japonais

> Femme : Ça te dirait de me dépanner 10 € ?
>
> Homme : Tu peux toujours rêver.
>
> Femme : Oh allez, ne me dis pas ça sur un ton pareil de «けんもほろろ(に)» !

« Oh allez, ne me dis pas ça avec une froideur aussi impassible ! »

Je cherche un (quasi-)équivalent français à l'expression japonaise «けんもほろろ», une phrase adverbiale, qui s'emploie pour décrire/souligner une attitude froide avec laquelle quelqu'un refuse catégoriquement une demande faite. Cette expression laisse entendre : « Qu'est-ce que ça te coûte de te montrer un peu moins détachée ? ».

Les mots «けん» et «ほろろ» désignent tous les deux le cri du faisan qui, soi-disant *froid* et *distant* de nature, ne s'approche des humains que très rarement – d'où son sens figuratif – même si ça me dépasse, comment on fait pour savoir dans quelle humeur se trouve vraiment un faisan... Bon, au moins le faisan tranche avec le pigeon qui se montre souvent amical envers l'homme, ne serait-ce que pour se nourrir.

Comment: Je pense a répondre avec mépris / être méprisant ou même snober mais ça ne colle pas vraiment avec le refus catégorique.
A noter qu'en Français le faisan est synonyme d'escroc (argot désuet) mais je n'ai pas d'explication sur l'origine.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not an expression, but  **sec/sèche** can be used figuratively to capture some of the notions presented by your question: e.g. *au cœur sec; refus sec ; ton sec*.

> [**Sec/Sèche**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sec) (from *TLFi* via
>   *CNRTL*, with emphasis added)
>   ...

II. − Au fig., domaine moral, intellectuel.[Qualifie une réalité abstr.]
 A. − …
B. − [Appliqué à une pers., à son comportement]

> 1. Qui est dépourvu de générosité, de sensibilité, de chaleur humaine. Synon. froid, glacial, indifférent, insensible, sévère.J'étais tombé
>      sous la férule de l'abbé Homan, jeune prêtre d'allure tortillante, à
>      l'esprit petit et soupçonneux, **au cœur sec**.  (BILLY,Introïbo,1939,
>      p. 26):
>      …
>      − En partic. Qui dénote la mauvaise humeur, le désir de
>      blesser. Synon. cassant, désobligeant.Geste, **refus**, salut, **ton
>      sec**; lettre, réponse sèche. Que de fois déjà, un coup d'œil hautain,
>      un mot sec de la Belcredi, avait déraciné jusqu'aux moindres fibres de
>      l'attendrissement qu'il sentait (BOURGES,Crépusc. dieux,1884, p.
>      245).Ne joue pas les ingénues, ça n'est pas ton emploi, dit Lucie
>      Belhomme d'une voix sèche (BEAUVOIR,Mandarins,1954, p. 270)

As for the use of *sec* in a pertinent expression, I’m not familiar with using the expression “sec comme … trique” to mean anything other than being skinny, but please see the following from the *TLFi/CNRTL* entry for [**Trique**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trique):

> Au fig. **Être insensible, sans cœur, indifférent**. J'avais pas une
>   bribe, pas un brimborion d'honneur... Je purulais de partout! Rebutant
>   dénaturé! J'avais ni tendresse, ni avenir...
>   **J'étais sec comme
>   trente-six mille triques!** (CELINE, Mort à crédit, 1936, p. 340) 
>   (emphasis added)

---

(As an aside, since your particular exchange/example involves at least one (& maybe two?) party who is arguably rather broke, using *sec* could also present the woman with an opportunity for a little word play in her response. For example, something like:
“Tu sais, ce n’est pas parce que je suis **à sec** qu’il faut me répondre si sèchement  avec un cœur/ton/refus si sec[s]!”)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a bien une expression à laquelle on pourrait penser, car elle est vraisemblablement assez proche :

> Avoir/Être* **un cœur de glace / un cœur de pierre**

C'est une image qui évoque un sujet (au moins en apparence) privé d'empathie, dénué d'émotions. Le lien sémantique heureux entre la froideur et la glace pourrait d'ailleurs constituer un argument supplémentaire.

La correspondance n'est évidemment pas exacte et on ne retrouve pas directement l'idée de refus catégorique dans *avoir un cœur de pierre*, donc on peut avoir des avis différents sur cet usage.

* probablement plus rare avec "être"

---

**English readers :**

I think of one expression somewhat fitting, or at least not too far I guess :

> Avoir/Être* un cœur de glace / un cœur de pierre

The image used here is implying a heart devoid of empathy, and it could correspond to original expression's *impassibility* idea.

There are differences, though, because *avoir un cœur de glace/pierre* doesn't especially refer to categorical refusal, rather lack of emotions/empathy.

It could depend on the usage so I'll live it to your judgement.

* arguably rarer with "être"

Answer (score 0):

"avec cet air de croque-mort" can also work. I personally use it.